# AWS RDS - change frequency of backup event in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Is there a way to temporarily stop log and database backup events in SQL Server hosted on RDS?
I found `managed_backup.sp_backup_config_basic` procedure but it is not available in RDS...

Currently log backups are done every 5 minutes and I would like to increase or disable this feature so it won't happen while ETL process is running.

I read that one way is to switch database instance into `SIMPLE` recovery mode which can be done by setting automated backup to `0` in AWS console. That I cannot do due to security requirements to have backup retention = `1`.

Thanks for every suggestions!

[image]

Comment: Did you ask AWS support? Functionality may vary based on your account / tier / service level etc.

Comment: Not yet, will do it after I finish my research.

Comment: Why do you want to stop log backups during your ETL? It seems like that would be a time of increased write activity for your database, so the transaction log will be more likely to grow and/or fill up at that time. Moreover, assuming that you leave the database in the full recovery model, you'll still be backing up the same amount of log eventually, just all at once instead of periodically.

Comment: I understand. So my only option is to set instance into `SIMPLE` recovery mode. I want to stop logging because we are reaching storage peak. ETL bulk inserts data and at the same time log's backups are taking tens of GBs. This drains instance's storage.

Comment: Simple mode breaks the log chain though, which isn't always good. Can't you just do some sort of backup expiration after a while? Or run BULK LOGGED mode